# Include several HTML pages with JavaScript into one PHP page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, include

Earlier I asked about fixing the clock below and BAM! The solution was nearly instantaneous. Since then I have successfully added several of these clocks to a single PHP page. One for Tokyo, one for London, one for Madrid and one for Denver - great. My problem (now) is that the only way I've been able to do this is to "include" individual PHP pages that are really made up of the [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) below. If you "View Source" on the PHP page, you see multiple HTML pages embedded within it complete with opening and closing HTML, head and body tags.

My question: is it OK to have multiple HTML pages embedded within one another? It works across all the major browsers ([Google Chrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome), Firefox, Internet Explorer, [Safari](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_%28web_browser%29) and [Opera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_%28web_browser%29)). Should I be going about this in a different way? I can't seem to call the header information within the head of my PHP file and make it work (specifically the call to jQuery & scripts/jclock.js). As long as it loads on the first clock it isn't necessary on the ones following, but I can't seem to get rid of the HTML and just use the JavaScript code per clock and echo '`<div id='us_pacific"></div>`' (which is how the clock gets printed to the page within the HTML within the body tags.)

Any thoughts?

Here is the clock:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jclock.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/homepage.css">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(
                function() {
                    if ($('#us_pacific .time').length>0){
                       $('#us_pacific .time').remove();
                    }

                    //Set the offset here
                    var offset = -7;
                    if (offset == '')
                        return;
                    $('#us_pacific').append('<div class="time"></div>');
                    var options = {
                        format:'<span class=\"dt\">%a, %d %b %H:%M</span>',
                        timeNotation: '12h',
                        am_pm: true,
                        utc:true,
                        utc_offset: offset
                    }
                    $('#us_pacific .time').jclock(options);
                });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="us_pacific"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To your question: '*is it OK to have multiple HTML pages embedded within one another?*', the answer is: no, you can't have multiple `html` tags inside one document, it would be an invalid document.

Assuming `jclock.js` is properly coded, it should be able to drive multiple instances.

Then you would add some extra container `div`'s in the HTML and modify your JavaScript code a little (peek in the other versions you have) to set extra clocks with their own options.

You could change your code to this (and re-factor it once it works to your liking):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jclock.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/homepage.css">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(
                function() {
                    var options; // This way you can re-use it without the 'var' keyword.

                    // Timezone 1
                    if ($('#us_pacific .time').length>0){
                        $('#us_pacific .time').remove();
                    }
                    $('#us_pacific').append('<div class="time"></div>');
                    options = {
                        format: '<span class=\"dt\">%a, %d %b %H:%M</span>',
                        timeNotation: '12h',
                        am_pm: true,
                        utc: true,
                        utc_offset: -7  // Now set the offset here
                    };
                    $('#us_pacific .time').jclock(options);

                    //Timezone 2
                    if ($('#eu .time').length>0){
                        $('#eu .time').remove();
                    }
                    $('#eu').append('<div class="time"></div>');
                    options = {
                        format: '<span class=\"dt\">%a, %d %b %H:%M</span>',
                        timeNotation: '12h',
                        am_pm: true,
                        utc: true,
                        utc_offset: 1  // Now set the offset here
                    };
                    $('#eu .time').jclock(options);
                });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="us_pacific"></div>
        <div id="eu"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: I am providing the visitor the option of choosing several clocks they'd like to see so the clocks that are displayed are dependent upon their selection. The included file is called up based on an if else statment so I can't see putting all the necessary code (following your suggestion) onto one page. Why can't I just strip the html tags out of this code and store each clock on its own page? What is preventing this from working and more importantly, how else could I go about this?

Comment: Scratch all that! I stepped away and digested your suggestion. Solution - I put all the clocks into one .js file and echo the necessary div based on my if else statments. Now there's only 1 call to jQuery, 1 call to 1 .js file... this is beautiful! Thank you!

Comment: Well, your php-script could echo parts of a javascript to. So where you currently include/combine full html-pages into one, you could also include just the difference (see `\\timezone 2') and have it echo a extra container-div in your html. Naturally it would be better to refactor the javascript (it just some options and a call), and php could then write (echo) the needed javascript-calls and their options as one simple line, maybe 2 to dynamically create the containing div to.. Better would be to have the data in a table with your time-zones that supplies the php-function.

Comment: I get what you're saying but it is slightly beyond my grasp at this early stage of my learning. If I understand you correctly, you're saying I can avoid rewriting the same code over & over in the .js file just to get a different output and instead echo the difference w/in my php? (You rock! This is the most fun I've had on a Friday night in a long time!)

Comment: Haha, that's what I'm saying, but you needed to see that for your self, and I figured the best way to do that is to show you what the php-generated document (html and js) could look like (rightclick>view source) to the browser, and let you see you see it just repeated (so you probably only need a table with locations and utc-offsets). You could even generate all different clocks (according to user-preference) client-side (if you pass it the that timezone table/array). Then you'd only use php (and a storage like mysql or simple cookies) to store the user-preferences.